# Как сделать так, чтобы footer у listView занимал все свободное место по высоте?

Tags: android, listview

Здравствуйте!
Имеется ListView, у которого динамически меняется содержимое через адаптер. Количество элементов каждый раз разное. Если элементы не достают до низа экрана, то видны элементы, которые находятся под ListView.
Задавать background **нельзя**, так как эти элементы должны быть видны через header. Возможно более элегантное решение, но я пока думаю, что надо каким-то образом играться с footer.

PS: match_parent - не работает
**UPD:** вот пример, как есть, нужно заполнить место снизу
[image]

**UPD[2]:** пока что придумал вот такой костыль, зато рабочий

```
public class MagicFooter extends View
{
    private static int absoluteHeight = -1;

    public MagicFooter(final Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public void invalidateHeight()
    {
        post(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                final Rect rect = locateView(MagicFooter.this);
                if (rect.top > 10)
                {
                    absoluteHeight = absoluteHeight > 0 ? absoluteHeight : getDisplayHeight();
                    final int h = absoluteHeight - rect.top;
                    setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, h));
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private int getDisplayHeight()
    {
        final WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        final DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);

        return displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    }

    private static Rect locateView(final View v)
    {
        int[] loc_int = new int[2];
        if (v == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        try
        {
            v.getLocationOnScreen(loc_int);
        }
        catch (NullPointerException npe)
        {
            return null;
        }
        Rect location = new Rect();
        location.left = loc_int[0];
        location.top = loc_int[1];
        location.right = location.left + v.getWidth();
        location.bottom = location.top + v.getHeight();
        return location;
    }

}
```

Comment: А что нельзя на лету задавать `ListView.addFooterView()`?

Comment: На сколько я помню футер и хидер можно задать только перед установкой адаптера.

Comment: @Barmaley как ответили уже в комментарии, футер можно задать только перед адаптером. и если было бы все так просто, я не шел бы сюда с вопросами, я потратил не один день, на поиск решения :)